# How do i resolve this error " subscript out of bounds"?

Tags: r

I would like to resolve the error I am getting while running the code below.

I have tried to debug the code but I am still getting the same error message.

```
glmer_results= evaluatr.univariate(analysis)
lapply(glmer_results,evaluatr.univariate.plot)
```

> Error in variance.vars[[i]] : subscript out of bounds
>   Calls:  ... eval -> eval -> evaluatr.univariate -> evaluatr.impact.pre
>
> Execution halted

Comment: Please take some time reviewing [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions, and what you can (and should) do in order to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58743354/edit) your question accordingly. In a nutshell, we should be able to copy&paste the code you give to reproduce the error you're seeing. If you can't share the original data (due to size, confidentiality etc.), you should provide representative & minimal mock data.

Comment: [continued] Also always explicitly state which external R libraries you've been using. For example, where is `evaluatr.univariate` from?

Comment: I can give the code and the data but is too long for this box
```

Comment: Don't post code/data in comments, as they might get deleted and don't allow for proper code formatting. Instead, edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

It is very hard to provide an answer without a reproducible example. However, the subscript out of bounds error message means that you are trying to subset an element, in this case `variance.vars` appears to be a list, but the element you are trying to fetch doesn't exist.

For example, if `variance.vars` is of length 2, but your index `i` goes up to three, then `variance.vars[[1]]` and `variance.vars[[2]]` will work and return the corresponding list element, but `variance.vars[[3]]` will fail and give the error message subscript out of bounds since the third list element doesn't exist. This is true if you try to extract elements from vectors or matrices as well.